# VB6: Standard deviation failure

Tags: vb6

I have a code to calculate the standard deviation:

```
Public Function StandardDeviation(ByRef arr() As Double) As Double

'standard deviation
Dim sum As Double
Dim sumSquare As Double
Dim value As Double
Dim count As Long
Dim index As Long
sum = 0
sumSquare = 0
value = 0
count = 0
index = 0

' evaluate sum of values
For index = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    value = arr(index)
    count = count + 1
    sum = sum + value
    sumSquare = sumSquare + value * value
Next

StandardDeviation = Sqr((sumSquare - (sum * sum / count)) / count)

End Function
```

It seems to work fine.

As it happens, the values are sometimes all the same, for example:

```
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
    0.419208025523645
```

In such a case, I get the error "Invalid argument" in this line:

```
StandardDeviation = Sqr((sumSquare - (sum * sum / count)) / count)
```

Does anybody see my mistake?

Comment: there is not real mistake, except that you are running into some rounding problems ... sumsquare is rounded down more often than the squasre of the sums, thereby you get a slightly negative result out of sumsquare-(sum*sum/count)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are running in to a problem where you are "trying" to take the square root of a negative value.  When the numbers are all the same, sumSquare should be the same as (sum * sum / count).

I would suggest the following code.

```
If ((sum * sum / count)) > sumSquare Then
    StandardDeviation = 0
Else
    StandardDeviation = Sqr((sumSquare - (sum * sum / count)) / count)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the calculation by removing the counter outside the loop

```
For index = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
  value = arr(index)
  sum = sum + value
  sumSquare = sumSquare + value * value
Next

count = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr)  + 1
```